# Is subtraction defined in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know  $(\mathbb{Z}_{2},+,*)$ is a field but I'm wondering if substraction is defined in it. I ask this because if I want to create a new Field $F:=\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ with the "Addition": $(a,b)\bigoplus(c,d)=(a-b,c-d)$ is this possible?

Comment: Subtracting $b$ from $a$ is just adding the inverse (wrt addition) of $b$ to $a$.

Comment: Subtraction is defined in *any* field.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is not a field.

Comment: Whenever a set has additive group structure, it automatically admits the operation of subtraction.  Subtraction is merely the addition of an additive inverse.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Why?

Comment: @JellyBelly: because $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$, at least with the natural definition of multiplication. On the other hand, if you define $(1,0)\cdot (1,1):=(1,1)=:(0,1)\cdot (0,1)$ and $(0,1)\cdot(1,1)=(1,0)$, you're on to something. But it's much easier to think about the $4$-element field as ${\bf F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$.

Comment: The problem is with multiplication: $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$ so it has zero divisors.

Comment: Your proposed "addition" on $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is very poorly behaved; it is not associative and does not have an identity.

Comment: @EricWofsey That was just an example, to describe why I'm asking it. I just wanted to know it subtraction was defined in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding in details:  In $\mathbb Z_2$, every element is its own additive inverse: $0+0=0$, $1+1=0$,  so $0=-0$,  $1=-1$. Another way of saying this is that $1+1=0$, and it makes this a "Field of Characteristic 2".

So,  $\forall b\in \mathbb Z_2,b=-b$.

Now, subtraction is defined as adding the additive inverse in general, so the way we define subtraction is $a-b=a+(-b)$.  But in fields of characteristic 2, such as $\mathbb Z_2,$  $-b=b$,  so we can simplify this to $a-b=a+(-b)=a+b$

Comment: Probably adding $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_2$, so it does not confuse anyone - meaning mostly those, who are getting started in groups, rings, fields etc.

Comment: @quapka thanks this help :)

Comment: @quapka Good idea, updated.

Comment: @Alan How do you know that $a−b=a+b$? Can you proof it with the axioms of a field (I mean Associativity, Commutativity, etc) or is it because of the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Comment: @JellyBelly Will add in details into answer